# Filling PDF Form using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-form

I want to fill a PDF template using PHP. Thats what I tried so far:

PDFtk - It can fill text fields but not image fields.

FPDF - Can't import template pdf.

FDFM - It can fill text fields but not image fields.

FPDI - Can import template and place image with coordinates but form fields are disappearing.

mPDF - Can generate but no filling text field.

Is there any way to fill text field, image field and checkboxes with PHP. If not what is the best way of doing this.

Comment: Are you searching for a free soltuion or would a paid one work, too?

Comment: I've looked at some paid libs too, but I think they are too expensive for this kind of job.

Comment: @M.Toy,  where you able to find a solution? I am looking for a way to embed images in fillable PDF.

Comment: I was planning to send PDF template from Android application to the webserver, fill the PDF there and send the filled PDF back to Android. Instead, I'm now using Apache PDFBox on Android side and handle the PDF tasks on Android device. I Still don't know how to handle this with PHP. But if you can run java on your platform you can use PDFBox. It handles a lot of things.